# Specifying edit paths in Drupal for FCKEditor?

Tags: drupal, fckeditor

With the FCKEditor, you can specifiy paths where the editor must be included. Eg.

```
node/add/email
```

Which works great, until you need to go back and EDIT that node. Which means you end at a path like so:

```
node/284/edit
```

Now, the fck editor no longer works, because the path isn't valid.

Is there any way that one can get the FCKEditor to work for both the normal path and the edit path of ONE SPECIFIC CONTENT TYPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this with stock the FCKEditor module. However, you can do it by using the [WYSIWYG API](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module, which allows you to specify WYWIWYG editors on a per-input-filter basis, and [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats), which allows you to set input filter formats on a per-node-type basis.

Comment: I just ended up hardcoding it directly in the fck module. for future versions what u suggested is probably the way to go... so I will definitely do that when the time comes. Thanks!

Comment: You can also include/exclude forms by their individual textarea ID's using fckeditor's visibility settings. But yes, it's time to start switching to the Wysiwyg API instead of twitching your FCK config.